# Unable to enable passenger module for apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

At the moment I uncomment this line in my apache configuration file, Apache only returns empty documents for all URLs on server.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

I am on CentOS, with ***ruby-2.1.0*** and passenger ***4.0.57***

At the moment I enable the module, all requests served by apache, for all vhosts on the server are blank, even if I disable completely with :

```
PassengerEnabled off
```

When I load the module and restart Apache, Apache restarts correctly, but I end up with this in my apache error log for all requests :

```
[Tue Jan 20 16:19:45.026338 2015] [core:notice] [pid 9645] AH00052: child pid 11555 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Passenger was installed with :

```
gem install passenger
```

And the apache module was built (correctly) with :

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it solved the problem :

```
chmod 777 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.57/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```